# deleting and inserting values in matrix multiplication python language

Tags: python, matrix, iteration

I want to iteratively multiply among the array of a matrix

```
matrix[0] = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
matrix[1] = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
matrix[3] = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
matrix[4] = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
matrix[5] = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
matrix[6] = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
```

results of multiplication matrix[0] and matrix[1] will be multiply to the next array of matrix, matrix[3]. This result will be again multiply with the next one. The process should be in sequence. 
any idea or solution? Thanks

Comment: If you want to multiply arrays in Python, either element-wise or linear algebra-style matrix multiplication, you should use `numpy`.

Comment: [Python 3.5 will add the `@` operator for matrix multiplication](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), if you're not in a hurry.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I knew that was being introduced, but is this actually going to work in vanilla Python for lists of lists, or is it just being made available for `numpy` etc.?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the whole idea is that it's being added as a basic Python feature.

Comment: im working with nao robot and the python package in my nao robot does not support numpy. unless i update the python nao software (which i try to avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a `reduce` operation:

[Python 2.7: built-in functions: reduce](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce)

Suppose you've defined this matrix multiplication function:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    num_r, num_c, num_i = len(a), len(b[0]), len(a[0])
    m = [num_c * [None] for r in range(num_r)]
    for r in range(num_r):
        for c in range(num_c):
            x = 0
            for i in range(num_i):
                x += a[r][i] * b[i][c]
            m[r][c] = x
    return m
```

And you have this list of matrices:

```
matrices = [[[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]],
            [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]],
            [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]],
            [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]],
            [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]],
            [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]]
```

Now you can multiply the matrices in sequence with one call to `reduce`:

```
print reduce(multiply, matrices)
```

Comment: I have another answer as below, but it seems your solution is more practical (better) than the one I have in mind. Thanks

Comment: it gives me an error when using the matrix format according to my question above. the error is , the error is num_r, num_c, num_i = len(a), len(b[0]), len(a[0])
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len().

Comment: Each argument to `multiply` has to be a two-dimensional array. Apparently you're passing it a one-dimensional array.

Comment: I just realised that. Thanks @ Michael Laszlo

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea (operation * is a simplication of matrix multplication process):

```
for i in range(6):
    A = matrix[i]
    B = matrix[i+1]
    C = A * B
    matrix [i+1] = C
return C
```

let me know if any other better way to do it. Thanks